# How can I see original form of printf function in C?

Tags: c

I'm using GCC as compiler. I wanted to know original form of printf function. So I found stdio.h file in /usr/include(I'm using CentOS 8.2 in GCP).

When I opened stdio.h file and found printf, something was written like

```
extern int printf(const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

What is extern and ... in this sentence? How and where can I see original form of printf function?

Comment: By "original form", do you mean the function's source code?

Comment: As a beginner you won't learn much from looking at the source code of `printf`, it's a really complicated function. Google _printf source code gnu_ you you'll find plenty of implementations. For the source code of _your_ `printf` it might be provided somewhere, but without more information we can't tell much more.

Comment: You can take a look here https://github.com/Intersec/lib-common/blob/master/src/core/str-iprintf.c#L467 but printf is not easy to jump in

Comment: The Standrad defines: `int printf(const char *format, ...);` that's is your reference. Everything else is implementation details and should not be of prinary interest.

Answer (score 0):

`extern` means that the function visibility is extended to the whole program. While for the `...` it represent an unspecified number of arguments for the format specifiers `%d - %ld etc.`. That means `printf` works if you want to print a string with 0 variables and with x variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What is extern and ... in this sentence? How and where can I see original form of printf function?

`extern` means external linkage. It tells the linker this symbol should be found in one of the objects or libraries being linked.

There are different implementations of `printf`. In most cases, all `printf` variants, such as `vprintf`, `fprintf` etc eventually calls `vfprintf`. The function `vfprintf` itself is very complicated. Most implementations use a table-lookup method where a handler corresponding to one of the `%` formatters is called to format the input.

You can see the implementation of `vfprintf` in `glibc` (one implementation of the standard library) here

https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c